# What transformation should be used when different transformations are required for each predictor?

Tags: multiple-regression, data-transformation

I am familiar with exponential, quadratic, power etc. transformations of variables in univariate regression when necessary based on non-normality in the relationship between the independent and dependent variable, such as skewness. My question is this: If, after reviewing each relationship via scatterplot between a dependent variable and multiple independent variables, it is determined that multiple and different transformations are needed, how does one determine the equation needed to transform the predictors? For instance, a reciprocal model may seem to fit best when comparing the DV to IV_1 and a logarithmic model when comparing DV to IV_2, but each transformation requires a different equation to back transform.

Comment: It's a great question, but to do justice to it requires a textbook.  A very abbreviated exposition, focusing on practical, exploratory methods, is available on my Web site at http://www.quantdec.com/misc/MAT8406/Meeting07 : link to the "diagnostic plots" PDF file.  In 24 heavily illustrated pages (with plenty of working `R` code) I provide a principled, quantitative, and effective workflow for addressing these problems.  It is addressed to people learning about multiple regression at the upper undergraduate to beginning graduate level, but using minimal mathematical background.

Comment: Thank you, whuber. I have added a follow up question in the comment under Data Science Dojo's answer, if you would like to chime in there as well.

Comment: If your aim's to build a predictive model on the data, setting aside some of them for this kind of exploratory analysis is a good idea. Another approach is to use polynomial or spline bases for the predictors, allowing approximation of even non-monotonic curvilinear relationships.

Comment: Thanks, @Scortchi, on both accounts. I am trying to avoid a polynomial or spline-based regression because I am unable to interpret the models as clearly is if it were a standard linear regression with transformed predictors. I actually ran into this problem recently as I could not interpret the GAM I had used, which used thin-plate regression, outside of looking at the multiple R of the model. It also had poor predictive power despite having good descriptive power. If you have any insight into the follow up question I posed in a comment to Data Science Dojo, I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is that you apply transformations to each IV individually, creating new IV columns with linear relationships to the DV.

For example, if I have two IVs $x_1$ and $x_2$ and a DV $y$, where $x_1$ has an exponential relationship to y (i.e. $e^{x_1}~\alpha~y$) and $x_2$ has a quadratic relationship to y (i.e. $x_2^2~\alpha~y$), then I will create two new IVs $x_1'$ and $x_2'$ such that $x_1' = e^{x_1}$ and $x_2' = x_2^2$. These new IVs have a linear relationship to $y$ by definition, allowing me to use a simple linear regression model. To extract useful coefficients from the linear regression, simply apply the inverse transformation (ln for $x_1'$ and square root for $x_2'$).

The longer, more complete answer can be found at the link in whuber's comment.

Comment: D.S.D., thank you very much for the detailed explanation. I will review whuber's website today. My follow up question is this, if you are willing: in order to back transform the predicted values to their original units of measure, do I take the inverse transformation of the coefficients in the multiple regression and then apply the model equation to the original IV's prior to their transformation? In addition, as I transform the predictors and back transform them, does the intercept require transformation? I would imagine so as the intercept would change based on the transformed variables.

Comment: @A.Vezey: I couldn't quite follow this: if you've transformed the independent variables, why would you need to transform the predicted values of the *dependent* variable? - they're still on the original scale.

Comment: @Scortchi, sorry for the confusion. Eg. in a power transformation log(y)= b0 + b1log(x), the back transformation of the predicted values are ŷ = 10^(b0 + b1log(x)). If I have one predictor that requires power transformation and another that requires a reciprocal model, in which case back transformation is ŷ = 1 / ( b0 + b1x ), how do I go about completing the back transformation of the predicted values? Does that make more sense?

Comment: Yes. I think it's different enough from this question that it's worth asking separately: you're also considering transformations of the dependent variable.

Comment: @Scortchi thanks for the tip, I will ask a separate question.